# broadcast ping on windows LAN

Tags: windows, networking, ping

I have a LAN of windows machine some running XP some running 2000, my broadcast ping times out all the time.

is it due to firewall? or some other setting in registry?

Comment: What do you mean "broadcast ping" Are you pinging the network broadcast address for the subnet?

Answer (score 4):

Windows boxes don't respond to broadcast pings and depending on the distro quite a few Linux boxes don't either. IIRC the same applies to BSD server defaults. It's not something you generally want systems to do, certainly not recently. The problem is not with the system you are sending the broadcast out from but from the remote systems ignoring it.

There may well be a registry key that can modify this (EnableBcastArpReply under the TCPIP service  key looks like a likely suspect) but it would need to be changed on all the targets which makes the exercise a bit pointless if you are using the broadcast to discover systems.

Comment: +1; the RFC (1122) actually permits broadcast pings to be silently discarded.

Comment: surpisingly i did not find the value in winxp registery, so i created one, but had no effect, my machine still does not respond to broadcast ping

Comment: Digging deeper into that key it seems that it is specifically there to support NLB clustering and not to reverse this behaviour. I can't see anything obvious that would turn it on, but then again it's not something that is going to be a feature that's much in demand. As mh pointed out the behaviour is RFC compliant and helpful for the most part given the potential for malware to abuse it.